# C# What is the best free and reliable database solution for storing configuration?

Tags: database, c#, .net, nosql, sqlite

I am about to choose a database solution for my c# project:

- to store simple configuration at first, bools, ints, paths etc.
- to store lots of small text blocks in the future
- probably to store small pictures in the future too

I need the database:

- to be lightweight
- to be embedded
- to be created per each user
- not to be used by more than one user at time
- to be free or very cheap
- transactions to be reliable
- to be scalable
- to be encrypted or at least masked

Initially I thought about some NoSQL, text databases but is it the correct path? How about SQLite or other solutions? Since the database must be embedded I shall probably choose from:

- SQLite
- SQL Server Compact
- Firebird Embedded
- Couchbase Lite
- LiteDB

LiteDB has got it all: it's lightweight, modern, noSQL, scalable, encryption is out of the box and supports .NET Core. Couchbase needs Enterprise Edition for encryption and the other databases are SQL or/and obsolete.

Does LiteDB have any cons?

Comment: What does "scalable" mean for you? Is it 1 GB of data, 8 GB, 256 GB or 2 TB? Or is it for load distribution on 2 servers, 20 servers, 100 servers? Or is it 10 simultenous users, or 1000 users or 1.000.000 users at the same time?

Comment: I hope you know about the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). Can you tell which 2 of those 3 properties are important to you? By "reliable transactions" I would imply that consistency is one of them.

Comment: The question has been edited. I think I'll go with LiteDB, what do You think about my choice?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would fit your requirements, and I hope it's not bad form to recommend something I have developed, but over the last few months I have been developing a simple, fast SQL database written in C#. By simple, I mean that avoided all complexities that I feel I don't need, such as NULL, and I have also tried to keep the source code simple and easy to understand, so anyone can easily add features they need ( it doesn't have encryption currently ). It's here: https://github.com/georgebarwood/Database

Comment: `I hope it's not bad form to recommend something I have developed` It's perfectly acceptable as long as you disclose that you've developed it (as you just did).

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a few years old now but it came up when searching on Google so thought I would add a response to anyone else who stumbles across it and maybe has similar questions.

Full transparency, I work for MongoDB but I still think it is a great developer data platform to consider.
MongoDB is performant, scalable, flexible schema (can apply a schema and validation if you wish) and can be deployed to multiple cloud providers (including the big 3 of AWS, Azure and GCP) with MongoDB Atlas.
It has a variety of products including free visualisations of your data with Charts, full-text search, Vector Search, support for federating Data across data sources and much more!
There are drivers for all the big languages including JavaScript, C#, Python, Java, Go, Rust, PHP, Ruby and more.
Plus best of all, there is a free forever tier that you can use to try out MongoDB and you can have one per project so can try out as many project ideas as you want!

The [Developer Center](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/) is a great place to start with lots of quick starts, tutorials and articles across a breadth of languages, frameworks and features!